# Looking for a sefer to help prepare for smicha

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, meat-and-milk, yoreh-deah, issur-vheter

I am currently learning hilchos taaroves and will soon be moving on to basar bechalav and melicha etc. in preparation for getting smicha. I have looked around and found countless (literally countless) sefarim that delve into the fine details of each halacha (lamdus).

What I would like is a sefer that puts together all the halachos in a simple way, not involving any lamdus at all. (I imagine that there might be some sefer out there written in question answer form where a question is posed and an answer given by referencing different simanim in order to answer the question.)

Although the sheilos u'tshuvos of later and modern day Achronim might be something like this, I am looking for something more simple that would only reference the Shulchan Aruch, Taz, Shach and very few other achronim.

Comment: There's a sefer of old Rabbanut tests

Comment: Do you want practice tests or a kitzur?

Comment: For practice tests, see http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/smicha-test#post-265430

Comment: and see Shu"t Heichal Shlomo. Those are old Rabbanut Smicha tests with answeres

Comment: Why only (primarily) those three?

Comment: @ertert3erte where can I find that

Answer (score 7):

Maarechet Hashulchan - it has the Shulchan Aruch and Rema, plus summaries of the Shach and Taz. There's a volume for taaruvot, one for melicha, and one for basar v'chalav. (Also other volumes, but those are the ones you asked about).

Comment: I'd also like to add Shut Heichal Shlomo to my previous recommendation. The questions are from former rabbanut exams, ordered by siman in the Shulchan Aruch, with answers that are basically summaries of the issues that draw on the main sources (Tur, Shulchan aruch, Shach, Taz), as well as other less common ones that may be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The Chochmas Adam is incredibly well-written.

Answer (score 4):

Iyunei Deah by Rabbi Ullman. It contains a collection of investigations ('iyunim') into Hilchos Yoreh Deah based on the bechinos of Rabbi Zalman Nechemia Goldberg in Isur v'Heter (melicha, basar b'chalav, ta'arovos) and Nida.

Answer (score 3):

Your question pretty much describes the Kur HaMivchan to a tee:

[Bassar B'Chalav](http://hebrewbooks.org/49237)
[Taaruvot](http://hebrewbooks.org/2848)
[Melicha](http://hebrewbooks.org/2847)

Comment: IIRC, Kur Hamivchan is primarily on later Achronim

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: I missed that last line when I read the question. In the Title Page to the sefer, he writes that the book covers all the Poskim; early, late and incuded the latest of the Achronim

Answer (score 2):

Halacha Shenuna. I only used it for Shabbos but it exists for all of shulchan aruch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sefer called Ikarei Hashulchan which has diagrams and halacha tablets . There is also Maadnei Hashulchan which is like a Mishna Brurah style for yoreh deah .Rabbi Yaakov Goldstein put out a smechia aid for baser bchalav and has melicha and taaruvos in PDF.His is the basics in the Shulchan Aruch and with some halacha lmaaseh.

Answer (score 2):

This probably doesn't apply to you anymore but if someone else is studying for their Semicha in Issur VeHeter, I found Maarechet Hashulchan really helpful as well as Rabbi Yaakov Goldstein's Semicha guides. You might also want to consider a book which sums up the different Shittot. For that I used Sefer Hashittot which I found to be useful.